# Kiosk Mode: Access to chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes API

Tags: google-chrome-os

Requirement: get deviceID of Chromebox.

As per the chrome developer, To fetch device ID we need to call chrome.enterprise API of chrome which is supported only in ChromeBox and in kiosk mode.

Here is the reference URL https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/enterprise_deviceAttributes/
Note: This API is only available to extensions force-installed by enterprise policy.

As per their guidelines, We tried all 3 ways but were unable to get success on it.

Please let me know if anyone can have tried for the same and able to succeed on it.

Thax much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time on it, I raise a concern to google support. I took follow-up regularly and finally they assigned a technical person to me who helped me to resolve my issue.

Here is my conversation with them and you can get the reference code which is working 100% correctly.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1314761

Thank you!!